# Using My.Application.Log over a custom stream writer

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application which require logging errors. I have looked into the various ways vb.net offers developers to log errors. I found an inbuilt method `My.Application.Log.WriteException`.

What is the advantage of using this method over a custom written stream writer?

Comment: It is very subjective.  Log.WriteException() hides a lot of information, a general philosophy in VB.NET.  Designed to not overwhelm a new programmer with too many obscure details.  Which is okay for small programs, not so great when they get big.  It all depends on how comfortable you are about what you see when more of the innards are revealed.

Comment: Look into System.Diagnostics.Trace and using Trace listeners to write to your log.

Comment: Depending on which type of logging you need, you may to use 3rd party solutions, such as this one: https://logger.codeplex.com/